# What is the meaning of 僝头？

Tags: meaning

I don't normally read about linguistics. Now I know why!

汉语里甚至有动词性主语加名词性谓语的句子，例如：

> 逃，僝头。(no more context, just this)

Maybe: Flee, you poor bastards!

**僝头**是什么意思呢？

I find 僝僽：

> 1.憔悴；烦恼。haggard
>
> 2.折磨。worried
>
> 3.埋怨；嗔怪。complain
>
> 4.排遣。distract oneself

Comment: 弱小；虚弱，如“以僝弱之人，博强横之人 ”

Comment: That sounds like an interesting paper actually.  Care to share the title? :)

Comment: 沈家煊，名词动词 ISBN978-7-100-11363-2 Recommended on this website by Betty. I see a lot of people here, they just assume, Western Grammar is correct, therefore Chinese must follow the rules of Western Grammar. Many Chinese linguists say, that is false.

Answer (score 2):

[孱头](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AD%B1%E5%A4%B4/2297337#:%7E:text=%E5%AD%B1%E5%A4%B4%E6%98%AF%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%8D%E6%B1%87,%E7%9A%84%E3%80%8A%E5%AE%98%E5%9C%BA%E7%8E%B0%E5%BD%A2%E8%AE%B0%E3%80%8B%E3%80%82) can be found in most dictionaries. Should just be an alternative spelling.

> 软弱无能的人(骂人的话)

**ABC**

> weakling; coward

Comment: So, it says: Flee, cowards! ???

Comment: @Pedroski Haha, yeah, something like that.